# The rank of a positive square matrix $A$ for $A^k = A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

> Determine the rank of $A$ if $A$ is a positive $n\times n$ matrix with $A^2 = A$. Give a geometric interpretation of $A$. What happens in the case when $A^k = A$ for some integer $k\geq 3$?

Clarifying, positive matrix ($A > 0$ or $A \succ 0$, since it might be confused with positive definiteness) is a matrix in which each element is positive.

I know from previous exercises that $\operatorname{rank} A = \operatorname{trace}A^{k-1}$ if $A^k = A$, but that holds without $A$ being positive so I assume that there is more to say about the rank. And likewise, I know that $A^2=A$ defines a projections, but that holds without $A$ being positive. So my question is how should one start, alternatively continue with said properties?

Perron's Theorem is known, but there is not more to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A^2 = A$, then $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $0$ and $1$.  However, by the Perron theorem, the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ is just $1$.

Similarly, if $A^k = A$, note By the Perron theorem that $A$ has the eigenvalue $1$ with multiplicity $1$ and no other eigenvalues of magnitude $1$.

Comment: I have been thinking a lot about the last part, $A^k = A$, but has not come to any considerable conclusion. As you mentioned, the largest (and of alg. mult. 1) eigenvalue is 1. In the first part, I used a diagonalisation argument, via minimal polynomial, to show that the diagonal matrix has rank 1 (and so has $A$). In this part, I cannot use this method since I do not know if the roots to $A^k - A=0$ are simple, and even if I could, the diagonal matrix would consist of many non-zero conjugating complex numbers. Am I looking towards the wrong direction, and where should I look instead?

Comment: You are looking in the right direction. $x^k-x$ has $k-1$ simple roots of magnitude $1$, and one simple root of $0$.