# If ^2= then both 0 and 1 are always eigenvalues of A

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know this question looks similar to this one: [If $A^2=A$ then $0$ and $1$ are the only eigenvalues of $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828870/if-a2-a-then-0-and-1-are-the-only-eigenvalues-of-a)

But the difference here is that *both* 0 and 1 are always eigenvalues of A whereas the answer to the other question shows *either* 0 *or* 1 are eigenvalues of A. This means the eigenvalue of A could be all 1s or all 0s.

Does this mean that the statement "If $^2=$ then both 0 and 1 are always eigenvalues of A" is false, Since $I_3$ satisfies $A^2= A$ but 0 is not an eigenvalue of A?

Comment: Correct, $0$ is not an eigenvalue of the identity matrix so it is incorrect to say that "*if $A^2 = A$ then $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$*"

Answer (score 1):

Indeed: look at all answers in the link you gave. They all state and prove that $0$ and $1$ are the only *possible* eigenvalues. Which only means that no other value can be an eigenvalue, but which does not force $0$ nor $1$ to be an eigenvalue. Geometrically, $A^2=A$ means $A$ is (the matrix of) a projection. The projection $0$ has only the eigenvalue $0.$ The projection $I$ has only the eigenvalue $1.$ All other projections have both eigenvalues.

Comment: I think you mean "identity", not "projection", in the penultimate sentence.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin No, I really meant "projection", in order to stress that $0$ and the identity $I$ are exceptional projections.